# How to perform a calculation using 2 rows from a multi-index df and append result as a new row?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a multi-index df like this:

```
                 foo  bar  now
2018-01-01 row1    0    1    2
           row2    3    4    5
           row3    6    7    8
           row4    9   10   11
2018-01-02 row1   12   13   14
           row2   15   16   17
           row3   18   19   20
           row4   21   22   23
2018-01-03 row1   24   25   26
           row2   27   28   29
           row3   30   31   32
           row4   33   34   35
```

I would like to append a new row5 with values from a calculation performed using other level1 rows, eg: row1 * row3.

The result from the calculation step should be:

```
                 foo  bar  now
2018-01-01 row5    0    7   16
2018-01-02 row5   etc..
2018-01-03 row5   etc..
```

And once new rows are appended to original, the resulting df would look like this:

```
                 foo  bar  now
2018-01-01 row1    0    1    2
           row2    3    4    5
           row3    6    7    8
           row4    9   10   11
           row5    0    7   16
2018-01-02 row1   12   13   14
           row2   15   16   17
           row3   18   19   20
           row4   21   22   23
           row5   etc...
2018-01-03 row1   24   25   26
           row2   27   28   29
           row3   30   31   32
           row4   33   34   35
           row5   etc...
```

I can get a calculation to output values across all rows in this manner but its not what I'm after:

`df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:,:], :] * df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:,:], :]`

I don't think broadcasting will work so I was going to try a loop but I couldn't get the calculation to work (returns a df with rows row1 and row3 as all NaN's):

`df.loc[pd.IndexSlice['2018-01-01', 'row1'], :] * df.loc[pd.IndexSlice['2018-01-01', 'row3'], :]`

Thanks in advance for any solutions, tips, resources to refer to :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way

```
s=df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:,'row1'],:]*df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:,'row3'],:].values
s=s.reset_index(level=1).assign(level_1='row5').set_index('level_1',append=True)
pd.concat([df,s]).sort_index()
                 foo  bar  now
2018-01-01 row1    0    1    2
           row2    3    4    5
           row3    6    7    8
           row4    9   10   11
           row5    0    7   16
2018-01-02 row1   12   13   14
           row2   15   16   17
           row3   18   19   20
           row4   21   22   23
           row5  216  247  280
2018-01-03 row1   24   25   26
           row2   27   28   29
           row3   30   31   32
           row4   33   34   35
           row5  720  775  832
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the calculation with alignment on the first index level, manually assigning back the second level and then concatenating and sorting:

```
import pandas as pd

idx = pd.IndexSlice
newdf = ((df.loc[idx[:, 'row1'], :].reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
          *df.loc[idx[:, 'row3'], :].reset_index(level=1, drop=True))
          .assign(idx1='row5')
          .set_index('idx1', append=True)
          .rename_axis([None, None]))

df = pd.concat([df, newdf]).sort_index()
```

#### Output:

```
                 foo  bar  now
2018-01-01 row1    0    1    2
           row2    3    4    5
           row3    6    7    8
           row4    9   10   11
           row5    0    7   16
2018-01-02 row1   12   13   14
           row2   15   16   17
           row3   18   19   20
           row4   21   22   23
           row5  216  247  280
2018-01-03 row1   24   25   26
           row2   27   28   29
           row3   30   31   32
           row4   33   34   35
           row5  720  775  832
```